# /Users folder (and any other high level folder) missing when trying to attach files to gmail

Tags: finder, gmail, attachments

When trying to attach a file located in /Users/"user"/ dir to a gmail email, the /Users/ folder doesn't exist, and there is no top level directory (i.e. /) for me to navigate to.  The workaround is that I am forced to copy the file to one of my "favorites" folders so that I can actually choose the file.  Verified this issue does not occur within the Finder app, however also verified that Windows does not have this problem.

Comment: Please help me understand this. How are you trying to get to /? Which application are you using.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  At the top of the little "pop down" window that shows your files to attach, I had to click on the drop down box (where it currently shows "Documents") to choose a different directory:

[image]